# How to iterate websql resultset using jquery each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m iterating websql resultset using for loop.And i want to iterate the resultset into Jquery each function.

```
   WebDB.transaction(function (transaction) {
   transaction.executeSql(SELECT Name FROM User, [],function(transaction,result){
            for(var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++)
            {
               alert(result.rows.item(i).Name);
            }
     });
 });
```

Is that possible to get like that?